# Where does YouTube put videos on my device?

Tags: youtube

I want to know where YouTube stores the videos when I go offline. I know it's on my device somewhere, but I can't figure out where.

Answer (score 0):

Try navigating to `Internal storage/Android/data/com.google.android.youtube/files/Offline/(system generated folder name)/streams`.
Alternatively, you could also use a video downloader that can retrieve videos from YouTube. There are several of these on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=video%20downloader%20from%20youtube&c=apps&docType=1&sp=CAFiHwoddmlkZW8gZG93bmxvYWRlciBmcm9tIHlvdXR1YmV6AhgAigECCAE%3D%3AS%3AANO1ljIiFZU&hl=en).